# Hadoop job suddenly fails

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

When running my Hadoop program, it suddenly fails without any obvious reason. I have attached the output message. It seems to be an IO problem. It tells something must go wrong in line 525 which is the line in which I run the job (line 525: `RunningJob runjob = JobClient.runJob(conf);`). As can be seen in the error message, it does not say any thing more about the error line.

I ran it a couple of times and it always gives me this error when it is 86% complete. Does anyone have some idea about the reason of failure?

```
13/10/14 10:25:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 79% reduce 6%
13/10/14 10:25:16 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 80% reduce 6%
13/10/14 10:25:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 81% reduce 6%
13/10/14 10:26:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 82% reduce 6%
13/10/14 10:26:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 83% reduce 6%
13/10/14 10:26:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 83% reduce 8%
13/10/14 10:27:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 84% reduce 8%
13/10/14 10:27:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 85% reduce 8%
13/10/14 10:28:29 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 86% reduce 8%
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201310101346_0102
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 31
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File System Counters
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of bytes read=316172729
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of bytes written=501348856
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of read operations=0
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of large read operations=0
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of write operations=0
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of bytes read=2144535743
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of read operations=128
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of write operations=0
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Failed map tasks=1
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=188
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=1
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=125
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Rack-local map tasks=63
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps in occupied   slots (ms)=211239444
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=406123
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after     reserving slots (ms)=0
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=45927922
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=45927922
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=11573153427
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Input split bytes=8000
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=48701007
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=3833295
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=3833295
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=86130400
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=13896142848
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=25477984256
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage  (bytes)=9854910464
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:    org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormatCounter
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:     BYTES_READ=2144450681
13/10/14 10:29:13 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job Failed: NA
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1373)
    at Mondrian3.main(Mondrian3.java:525)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
```

Comment: Line 525 of Mondrian3.java

Comment: Thanks for removing the image. That looks better now. However, we still cannot help you any further than saying that your problem is in line 525 of Mondrian3.java. Can you paste that class?

Comment: Whenever this happens, there's almost always something in the job log that hints at or declares the failure. If not, try adding some debug output in the class to show particular input values at the failure. That may give you what you need to modify your UT to tickle this bug.

Comment: there isn't anything in the log file about this failure. However, before the job ends, there are many failed tasks due to `` failed to report status for 600 seconds. Killing!``. Each mapper constructs a tree out of a distributed file and then finds the leaf node to which each record (within each chunk) belongs. I don't get what there are many failed tasks. What can be the reason?